# Method running even outside the loop

Tags: java

I have this method that works as a menu for other methods:

```
public static void menu(){

    boolean works = true;

    System.out.println("\n1 - Register Car\t2 - Register Client\t3 - Rent car\n4 - Returning car\t5 - Show list\t6 - Exit\n");
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    int operacao = scan.nextInt();

    do {
        if (operacao == 1) {
            cadVeiculo();
        } else if (operacao == 2) {
            cadCliente();
        } else if (operacao == 3) {
            locar();
        } else if (operacao == 4) {
            devolver();
        } else if (operacao == 5) {
            listar();
        } else if (operacao == 6){
            works= false;
        }
    } while (works);
}
```

What I don't understand is, when I run the program and press "6" the program stop, ok. But when I press "1" for example to register a car and after that press "6" to exit the program, the program keep asking me to enter another input.

What I expected is that when I operate the program and press "6" to exit it just stops the program altogether.

Comment: You're asking only once. You need to move the Line where you assign the scanned int to the operacao variable inside the do-while loop, just before the first if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `println` and the `scanner.nextInt()` line within the *do-while* loop:

Here is a modified example that just prints out the method names:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
  }

  public static void menu() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean works = true;
    do {
      System.out.println(
          "\n1 - Register Car\t2 - Register Client\t3 - Rent car\n4 - Returning car\t5 - Show list\t6 - Exit\n");
      System.out.print("Input: ");
      int operacao = scan.nextInt();
      if (operacao == 1) {
        System.out.println("cadVeiculo();");
      } else if (operacao == 2) {
        System.out.println("cadCliente();");
      } else if (operacao == 3) {
        System.out.println("locar();");
      } else if (operacao == 4) {
        System.out.println("devolver();");
      } else if (operacao == 5) {
        System.out.println("listar();");
      } else if (operacao == 6) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        works = false;
      }
    } while (works);
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
1 - Register Car    2 - Register Client 3 - Rent car
4 - Returning car   5 - Show list   6 - Exit

Input: 1
cadVeiculo();

1 - Register Car    2 - Register Client 3 - Rent car
4 - Returning car   5 - Show list   6 - Exit

Input: 3
locar();

1 - Register Car    2 - Register Client 3 - Rent car
4 - Returning car   5 - Show list   6 - Exit

Input: 4
devolver();

1 - Register Car    2 - Register Client 3 - Rent car
4 - Returning car   5 - Show list   6 - Exit

Input: 6
Goodbye!
```